# Existence of a differentiable path passing through 3 points in $R^{n}$.

Tags: analysis

Show that, given any three points of $R^{n}$, there is a differentiable path through these three points.

I'm having difficulty solving this problem. 
I'm trying to solve this problem as follows: 
Let $a,b,c \in R^{n}$. Taking two straight paths connecting a and b, b and c. Note that b is not differentiable. My idea was to try to reparametrize this path in order to make it differentiable at this point, but I am have difficulty. Could someone help me? Thank You!

Comment: Since three points lie in a plane, you can simplify the problem and only consider three points in R^2. Maybe just find a parabola that goes through them? Or use the so-called "Bezier curves" or whatever that programmers use?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Actually three points are in a plane. So we can just consider the situation in $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, there is a plane containing the three points. Now, given three points, you can find a circle going through these three points. Restrict the circle to a path going through the three points and you have your smooth path.